# On my Windows 2008 Server (standard), the time synchronization option is missing. How do I get it back?

Tags: sync, windows-server-2008, date-time

Normally if I go into date and time settings there's an option to specify the time synchronization server, but on my Windows 2008 Server, the option is missing. Where did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you join an active directory domain on the server? If so it will use the AD server for time.